# Can I use PHP reserved variable as my variable?

Tags: php

PHP has list of reserved variables, [visit here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.php).
If i use one of the reserved keyword as my variable, it is working for me.

```
<?php
   $_GET = 10;
   echo $_GET;//10
?>
```

Please correct me, if my understanding is wrong?

Comment: Don't do this ... That's a global array variable. Do `$_GET['myvar']=10` .. if you have to.

Comment: please, please don't do this.

Comment: Innocent kittens die when you do that. Think about the kittens!

Answer (score 11):

"Predefined" is not the same as "reserved". PHP gives these variables default values, but you can still use their names for your own purposes. But you shouldn't, since it's poor style.

Answer (score 1):

If you pass GET data into that file like `http://example.com/example.php?id=1`

Then it will conflict with your $_GET variable..

`$_GET = Array { [id] => 1 }`

After your declaration the value will be changed as

`$_GET = 10`

It will overwrite the old value..

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine a situation where you would want to do what you're suggesting.

in the case of $_GET, $_SESSION, they are arrays where you can assign a key value pair at will, that's what they're designed for.

```
$_SESSION["UID"]=username;
```

for example

Answer (score -5):

$_GET is not a  reserved variable.

[$_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) is an associative array of variables passed to the current script via the URL parameters. Also is a superglobal. Read the documentation to learn how to use it

You should use like

```
$_GET['key']=10;//good
```

Doing

```
$_GET =10;//bad
```

**will overwrite the value and it works but is a very wrong way to use a superglobal and they were not designed to work that way**

Comment: You're not wrong, but you don't address the question. (not the downvoter)

Comment: Can I use PHP reserved varible as my variable? No, you can't

Comment: Except that `$_GET` isn't a "reserved variable" in the first place.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I updated my answer, why is deleted?, in the second line I explain what is $_GET

Comment: You *still* haven't addressed the question. What you have written is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams with all the respect you deserve, the same with your answer, I think that the question deserve answer like yours or mine

Comment: @EmilioGort with all the respect you deserve, it is not the case. Ignacio actually explains why the assignment succeeds. Your post rather seems to indicate it should fail.